# Is there a way to summarize multiple flag columns into only one using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these columns in a dataframe:

```
a   b   c   d   x
0   1   0   0   kevin
1   0   0   0   john
0   0   1   0   mary
1   0   0   0   jessica
0   0   0   1   joe
```

I need to turn the first four columns into only one. Something like this:

```
new_col   x 
b         kevin
a         john
c         mary
a         jessica
d         joe
```

Is there a pandas function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `dot`

```
df['new'] = df.loc[:,'a':'d'].dot(df.columns[:-1])
Out[306]: 
0    b
1    a
2    c
3    a
4    d
dtype: object
```

If only one 1 per row with can check `idxmax`

```
df.loc[:,'a':'d'].idxmax(1)
Out[307]: 
0    b
1    a
2    c
3    a
4    d
dtype: object
```